# How do you make certain Facebook permissions, like user_friends, required instead of optional?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently using the Facebook API for an app that requires a user's friends list for the app to be functional.

My current scope (using the javascrkipt sdk) is: scope: "public_profile,user_friends".

Currently when a user logs on for the first time, they have an option to disable "user friends" (Which allows an app to access to their friends list of people who are already on the app).

Other apps can force the "user_friends/friends-list" field to be required when they first logon. How is this achieved?

Comment: Note - i'm not asking for access to a user's whole friends list, just the friends who are already on the app.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know this already, but you can't do this anymore.

Check this answer out: [Force Facebook email and user_friends permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909723/force-facebook-email-and-user-friends-permissions)