# Force Facebook email and user_friends permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to set `user_friends` and `email` permissions as **Required**, like Tinder.

**Tinder Permissions:**

[image: Tinder permissions]

**My Permissions:**

[image: My permissions]

I open my session with this:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"] allowLoginUI:NO completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t force permissions anymore. Tinder is still using a v1.0 App, you can´t use v1.0 in a newer App and it will be upgraded to v2.0 after April 2015.

You can only check if the user authorized specific permissions later, with the `/me/permissions` endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/permissions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will have to work around this myself it seems. :(

Comment: Make sure that you not pop the dialog again if they say no. Instead explain why you need them and have a button that they user can click if they change their mind and want to give them to you